# After adding ASP.NET Idenity to a project can't update database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have a solution with 2 projects. One is a project of Web Application (Razor Pages). The second one is a project Class Library. Database that I use is LocalDB in Visual Studio. Model of Blogger.Data was created using Code First approach.

[image: Solution explorer]

I added ASP.NET Identity. Created User model, added migration and updated a database. Could register, log in and did some work with authorization to Razor Pages.

Wanted to change and update Blog class and update database. Unfortunately error occured after `dotnet ef database update`. I have no idea what can I do to resolve it.

The error message in Command Line:

> Unable to create an object of type 'BloggerDbContext'.

I'm beginner, sorry if I wrote something incomprehensibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to User @Rajdeep Debnath I worked it out.

I ran `dotnet ef database update --context BloggerDbContext --project Blogger/Blogger.csproj` from Package Manager Console. I have two DbContext and my .csproj file is in different project so I needed to specify that.

Answer (score 1):

Run this `dotnet ef database update` for project Blogger.Data from project manager console; sometime the project changes to main project and you may get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check a couple of things just add below line while running migration may be it can help

add-migration pqr -verbose

Also check you dont have multiple projects in startup